# How to re-fetch events when you navigate months?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am working on fullcalendar + Nylas (Calendar Sync service).
Nylas is fetching only 1000 event per request from server. so I need re fetch new events on navigate every month full calendar. I need js code only for fullcalendar refetching event while navigate the months.

Comment: Give me an example, just an alert message on navigate next with navigate date range.

Comment: Does Nylas give you the option to specify the date range for which you require the events? I.e. to send a start date and end date to the server, and only receive back events which fall within that range. If you can do that, then implement your events using this pattern: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function . Then fullCalendar will provide your callback with the correct start and end dates of the current view. You can send these to the server. And then when the user navigates the months, fullCalendar automatically runs your callback again, providing different start/end dates

Answer (score 1):

The Nylas [Events endpoint](https://docs.nylas.com/reference#get-events) has the option to filter GET requests by starts_after. You can make a request that searches from the start of the month and filter out any events that happen in the following month.